# Running process nohup

Tags: linux, bash, putty, pid, nohup

There is a benchmarking process, which should be run on a system. It takes maybe a day, so I would like to run it nohup. I use this command:

```
nohup bash ./run_terasort.sh > terasort.out 2>&1 &
```

After that I can see with `PID` in `jobs -l` output, but after closing PuTTy it stops(as I can see, when I login again).

This is a `KVM` virtualized machine.

Comment: Side note: consider `screen` or `tmux`

Comment: Did you try `nohup /path/to/run_terasort.sh > out 2>&1 &`? (If you really need the `bash` then I think you're doing something non-optimally). Good luck.

Comment: @shellter: It isn't solved the problem.

Comment: Sorry, I just thought it would be worth dbl-checking as I don't have a way to reproduce your problem. And now you have added this is a KVM, of which I have only fleeting knowledge. The simplest thing for you is to run it under `screen` or `tmux`. Good luck.

Comment: What is the ppid of the process after it is executed?

Comment: Try `setsid` instead of `nohup`, and also then redirect stdin with `</dev/null`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `nohup` right from what I know. But you have an issue detecting the process.

`jobs -l` only give the processes of current session. Rather try the below to display the process started in your initial session:

```
ps -eafww|grep run_terasort.sh|grep -v grep
```